# ConnectionException while trying to query SymbolTable

Tags: tooling-api, tooling

While trying to query SymbolTable from ApexClassMember I recieve ConnectionException.

```
ToolingConnection con = ...;//get connection here
String query = "SELECT FullName, SymbolTable FROM ApexClassMember";
QueryResult qr = con.query(query);//it causes exception
```

If I am doing query without `SymbolTable` everything is ok.
Here is exception:

```
com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com:returnType' but found 'urn:tooling.soap.sforce.com:visibility'
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.verifyTag(TypeMapper.java:411)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.verifyElement(TypeMapper.java:440)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.Method.setReturnType(Method.java:36)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.Method.loadFields(Method.java:71)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.Method.load(Method.java:64)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:662)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readArray(TypeMapper.java:553)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:531)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.SymbolTable.setMethods(SymbolTable.java:177)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.SymbolTable.loadFields(SymbolTable.java:392)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.SymbolTable.load(SymbolTable.java:381)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:662)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:529)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.ApexClassMember.setSymbolTable(ApexClassMember.java:485)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.ApexClassMember.loadFields(ApexClassMember.java:580)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.ApexClassMember.load(ApexClassMember.java:557)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:662)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readArray(TypeMapper.java:553)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:531)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.QueryResult.setRecords(QueryResult.java:153)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.QueryResult.loadFields(QueryResult.java:250)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.QueryResult.load(QueryResult.java:240)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:662)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:529)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.QueryResponse_element.setResult(QueryResponse_element.java:37)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.QueryResponse_element.loadFields(QueryResponse_element.java:68)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.QueryResponse_element.load(QueryResponse_element.java:62)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readSingle(TypeMapper.java:662)
at com.sforce.ws.bind.TypeMapper.readObject(TypeMapper.java:529)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.bind(SoapConnection.java:180)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.receive(SoapConnection.java:154)
at com.sforce.ws.transport.SoapConnection.send(SoapConnection.java:99)
at com.sforce.soap.tooling.ToolingConnection.query(ToolingConnection.java:588)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of QueryResult, what if you try using List<ApexClassMember>?

Comment: @Goki, thank you, but the problem causes when i'm trying to query, namely when i'm doing `con.query(query)`. I think that problem is in the salesforce libraries. Maybe someone can suggest solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by setting correct endpoint API version when getting `ToolingConnection`.